# Implement searchbar to tableview with custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, searchbar

I created a tableview with custom cell and im struggling now to add a searchbar.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

var SVGdata = [SVG]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    createSVGdata()
}

// Create movies data
func createSVGdata() {
    SVGdata.append(SVG(SVGArtikel: "Art. 1", SVGGesetzestext: "Das darfst du nicht tun"))
    SVGdata.append(SVG(SVGArtikel: "Art. 2", SVGGesetzestext: "Und das erst recht nicht"))

}

// TableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return SVGdata.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SVGCell", for: indexPath)

    let sVG = SVGdata[indexPath.row]
    if let SVGCell = cell as? SVGCell {
        SVGCell.setSVG(sVG)
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

There are thousands of videos how to search in a simple array. But not for my solution.

Comment: can you explain what's the specific problem you are facing? what kind of search you are looking for? for example : search like default iOS contact app?

Comment: i will create some Text for each Table (row) . The searchbar is kind of filter. I need to display all rows with the searched word or number in it.

Comment: I have added an answer , please check

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using UISearchBar.
First  add a UISearchBar  in story board on the same viewController where your tableView is (Add the search bar on top of table view like iOS. Contact app) then add reference like below  code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

Then in viewDidLoad add delegate :

```
self.searchBar.delegate = self
```

I have two dataArray allData, filteredData.  in allData I have kept all data of the table(Didn’t change it anywhere) and filteredData used to get the filtered result. 
So, after populating data into allData , I have done from (viewWillAppear):

```
filteredData = allData
```

So , All tableView delegates, datasources is used the filteredData.
Then make extension of your viewController (making extension is not mandatory ) to conform UISearchBarDelegate :

**As you use SVGdata( I used filteredData) for tableView, after filtering you have to put all filtered data into SVGdata before reloading the table.**

```
extension YourViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // searchText will contain user input
    // in allData I have kept all data of the table
    // filteredData used to get the filtered result
        if (searchText == ""){
            filteredData = allData
        }
        else{
            filteredData = []
        // you can do any kind of filtering here based on user input
            filteredData = allData.filter{
                $0.cName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            }   
        }
    // lastly you need to update tableView using filteredData so that the filtered rows are only shown
    //As you use SVGdata for tableView, after filtering you have to put all filtered data into SVGdata before reloading the table.
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. Unfortunately i didnt get it running. Is it possible for you to fix my project? Thx in advance

Comment: what was the problem? can you give a screenshot of that viewController where tableview and search bar are included in StoryBoard?

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways of adding a search bar when you have a TableView, so I recommend you to decide first which implementation suits better for your app:

First one, if you have a UINavigationController, you can use a native implementation of the searchbar that will appear in the navigation bar. I mean, you first need a UINavitationController added to your view controller, programmatically or through storyboard. Then, you should create a UISearchController and associated to the UINavigationController. Lastly, listen for events through UISearchController Delegate occurring in navigation search bar so you can update you view.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

The second way is a searchbar which is associated to a tableView through his header, read several tutorials until you make it.

https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-ios-tutorial